# Bootstrapping formula for TD learning in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, bootstraping

In Reinforcement Learning (Sutton & Barto, 2018), p.120, equations (6.3)-(6.4)
, to explain the idea of bootstrapping in Temporal-difference learning:

\begin{equation}
v_{\pi}(s) := E_{\pi}[G_t|S_t=s]\ (6.3) \\
= E_{\pi}[R_{t+1}+\gamma G_{t+1}|S_t=s] \ (\text{from}\ (3.9))\\
= E_{\pi}[R_{t+1}+\gamma v_{\pi}(S_{t+1})|S_t=s] \ (6.4)
\end{equation}

I am confused about the logic from the second line to (6.4). Why is $E_{\pi}[G_{t+1}|S_t=s] = E_{\pi}[v_{\pi}(S_{t+1})|S_t=s]$? The term $v_{\pi}(S_{t+1})$ also does not really make sense to my intuition because I interpret $S_{t+1}$ as a random variable. How can the value function take a random variable as the input?